# Syntax problem with Inputs and SQLDF library

Tags: r

I'm having a peoblem with syntax in RShiny.

If i have some input called that way:

```
insertUI(
        selector = "#pesquisa",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = selectInput(
          "grau",
          label = "Grau:",
          choices = df$GRAU
        )
      )
```

How can i handle a the data using SQLDF?
I'm trying this:

```
test <- sqldf('select something
                    from my_df
                    where something = (input$grau)
                    ')
```

There is an error in my code, but i could not find it.

I have to put my selected choise in the *"grau"* input in the *WHERE* condition.

Thx!

Ps.:

library("sqldf")

database: Oracle

Comment: `input$grau` is not SQL. sqldf supports 4 backends but Oracle is not one of them.  See the sqldf github page and search for `fn$` on that page to see examples of how you can insert strings in your SQL string.

Comment: My DF is already updated and it's called "my_df".

I want to use the SQLDF to make a filter using my input's values and create another DF called "test". I think it does not remind the Oracle Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query argument for sqldf() is a string, you cannot pass in a variable directly. To get around this, you can use the sprintf() function as shown below:

```
test <- sqldf(sprintf("select something
                from my_df
                where something = '%s'
                ",input$grau))
```

In this example, sprintf() replaces '%s' with the value of the input$grau variable. Then, sqldf() can look for where something equals that variable's value, instead of looking for the string 'input$grau'.

Please let me know if this works.